# Magento addFieldToFilter: how to getCollection() from table using forigen key

Tags: magento, filter

I am new to magento, tried to solved it, but not succeeded.
My Problem is that,I have to apply "addFieldToFilter" filter on base if "store_id" , I have to drop all orders for a specific store/stores from collection on table

```
sales_flat_order
```

but store_id is in table

```
sales_flat_order_address
```

"sales_flat_order_address" table's primary key "entity_id" is used as foreign key in  "sales_flat_order_address"  as "parent_id", I have written a query some thing like this,

```
  $ordercollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $ordercollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.store_id',array('store_id'=>'sfoa.store_id'));
    $ordercollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array('neq'=>'555'));
```

I don't understand it, And it's not working

Comment: my bad, I don't need to drop them from db, I don't want the order for specific store in my collection, i.e, if store_id =33,is passed to fitter all the order's for store_id=33 should not be in collection:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to filter your orders by store id

```
    $ordercollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $ordercollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array('neq'=>'4'));
    $ordercollection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_address', "main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id",array('country_id'));
```

Comment: One sec please, what is this doing "array('country_id')"

Comment: Can you have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996385/how-to-use-join-in-magento-to-get-colloection

Comment: country_id is column name which you want to select from  table sales_flat_order_address if you want all columns remove array('country_id) as $ordercollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $ordercollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array('neq'=>'4'));
    $ordercollection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_address', "main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id AND sales_flat_order_address.address_type='shipping'");

Comment: echo $ordercollection->getSelect()->__toString();exit;  and fire sql query on your database change store id from 4 to your store id

Comment: Bro it's not working, as I said, have you looked into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996385/how-to-use-join-in-magento-to-get-colloection

Comment: SELECT `main_table`.*, `sales_flat_order_address`.* FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id WHERE (store_id != '4') run this on your database change store id

Comment: $ordercollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $ordercollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array('neq'=>'4'));
    $ordercollection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_address', "main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id"); this is the same code which i have already post please check

Comment: if you want to see the result use echo <pre>';  print_r($ordercollection->getData());

Comment: This is working fine on  database, and returning correct no rows (20 rows), but in magento when I place the code, And try to run, it is stuck, and if I do following , nothing in total  '$ordercollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$ordercollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array('neq'=>'555')); 
$ordercollection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_address', "main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id");
 $total = $orderCollection->count();'

Comment: I think, it is not returning record in collection,or some thing other is being happen here, I need to save these collection's data in .xml file, simple query is working and being saved in .xml file, but I got stuck here

Answer (score 0):

try this extension for deleting orders..
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html

Comment: my bad I don't need to drop them from db, I don't want the order for specific store in my collection, i.e, if store_id =33,is passed to fitter all the order's for store_id=33 should not be lodeed: