# How to use join in magento to get colloection

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, filter

I need to convert following sql query into magento to get collection.

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address ON sales_flat_order.entity_id=sales_flat_order_address.parent_id And sales_flat_order_address.store_id!=x;
```

I tried this, I know it's wrong, just for idea what am I trying to do, where "555" is x in sql query

```
 $ordercollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $ordercollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id',array(,=>'sfoa.store_id'));
    $ordercollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array('neq'=>'555'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id', "");
$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.store_id',array('neq'=>'555'));
```

Output

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `sfoa` ON main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id WHERE (main_table.store_id != '555')
```

SFOA doesn't include a `store_id` column, so I've updated my collection query above.

```
foreach($orderCollection as $collection) {
    // do something
    //var_dump($collection->getData());die();
}
```

Comment: This is not returning any thing

Comment: this is working fine on db, in magneto it's not 'Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(); $ordercollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',array('neq'=>'555')); $ordercollection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_address', "main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id");'

Comment: If you `$ordercollection->getSelect()->__toString()` does this compare to your SQL?

Comment: SELECT main_table.*, sales_flat_order_address.* FROM sales_flat_order AS main_table LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id WHERE (store_id != '555')

Comment: Above is sql of my previous comment, it gives what I want, you can see in comments at this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993812/magento-addfieldtofilter-how-to-getcollection-from-table-using-forigen-key/33997518?noredirect=1#comment55752887_33997518

Comment: But this is not returning any thing in magento, query works fine on db directly

Comment: Actually, your SQL above is invalid.  There is no store_id on sfoa?

Comment: Yes, there is , store_id in "sales_flat_order_address",

Comment: This is my custom column in  "sales_flat_order_address"